# Replace only "," by "." in a String Python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataset

i'm using a dataset that contains a column "Streams" dtype: object and i just need to replace "," by "." to later use pandas.to_numeric() and convert String by float64. Is there a way to replace only the
characters and keep the numbers?

Example: 48,633,449 to 48.633.449

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dados = pd.read_csv("spotify_dataset.csv")

dados.dropna()
dados['Streams'].replace(",", ".")
dados['Streams'] = pd.to_numeric(dados['Streams'])
dados.head()
```

and got this:

> **ValueError: Unable to parse string "48,633,449" at position 0**

[Error]

[image: 1]

Comment: if you change `48,633,449` to `48.633.449` How can you later on convert to numeric? What number is `1.2.3`?? No you should consider changing `48,633,449` to `48633449`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) instead of just `.replace`.

```
dados['Streams'] = pd.to_numeric(dados['Streams'].str.replace(",", ""))
```

Also, I don't think your intention is to replace commas with decimals. That would result in the same error since multiple decimals are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing away your `replace` since you are not assigning it to anything. Unless you explicitly use `inplace=True` arguments, Pandas methods do not change the current instance of an object (Series, Dataframes).

You can provide the result of `replace` as the argument to the `to_numeric` function

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dados = pd.read_csv("spotify_dataset.csv")

dados = dados.dropna()
dados['Streams'] = pd.to_numeric(dados['Streams'].replace(",", "."))
dados.head()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dados = pd.read_csv("spotify_dataset.csv")

dados = dados.dropna()
dados['Streams'] = dados['Streams'].replace(",", ".")
dados['Streams'] = pd.to_numeric(dados['Streams'])
dados.head()
```

Comment: even if the answer is correct, it should include an explanation in some form to say what the code is doing